sfdx-mohanc-plugins export special characters not exported propperly in file
I have installed and set up mohanc as described in this blog: https://www.salesforceblogger.com/2020/08/19/export-your-einstein-analytics-datasets/
Sadly, I have german letters in the data like Ö, Ä, Ü, ß and the export replaces this characters with ├╝, ├ñ, ├ñ and similar. In the terminal preview it looks fine.
Is there a command to fix that?


What is the character encoding of your input data? What is the character encoding in the web interface? This looks like fairly run of the mill mojibake where presumably you have UTF-8 (like you should) but using some obsolete 8-bit character encoding to view it (doesn't look like Windows-1252; probably something fuglier still). The Stack Overflow character-encoding tag info page has some basic introductory reading.

The input is from analytics studio. Not sure what the standard encoding is for that. Output I have set to UTF-8, but it did not help

I solved it with a workaround by capturing the output of sf mohanc ea dataset export and saving it 'manually' via a bash script:
output_file="exported_data.csv"
LANG=C.UTF-8 sf mohanc ea dataset export -e DATASETID> "$output_file"

